# Как узнать internal Ip address в скрипте ?

Tags: php, javascript

Вот, например, в [ip address location](http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/) определяется не только внешний ip, но и внутренний. Как это делается? Можно ли внутренний ip определить средствами php?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй этот код:

```
<?php

function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
echo getRealIpAddr();
?>
```

**upd**.подобная информация получается на стороне клиента с помощью java, например [ip-lookup.net](http://ip-lookup.net) (да и сайт по твоей ссыле также использует данный класс).
В нем используется класс `myaddress.class` (www.reglos.de/myaddress/MyAddress.html), который в своей реализации использует:

```
 Socket socket;
    ...
    InetAddress internal = socket.getLocalAddress();
    String localIp = internal.getHostAddress();
```

На примере вышеприведенного сайта (можешь сам посмотреть их html код), используется функция:

```
function get_lan_address() {
    cursor(1);
    $("lan_address").innerHTML = '<img src="/img/wait_2.gif" height="5" width="120" alt="" />';
    $("lan_address_applet").innerHTML = '<applet code="MyAddress.class" mayscript="true" width="0" height="0">' + '<param name="status" value="" />' + '<param name="call" value="set_lan_address" />' + "</applet>";
    return false
}
```

Ну и собственно [пример](http://tester.sexyi.am/lan.html) кода реализующего данный функционал: lan.html (в каталоге размещаем файл: [MyAddress.class](http://reglos.de/myaddress/download/MyAddress.class)).

```
<html>
<span id="lanip"><b>Router IP Address Testing...</b></span>
<script> function MyAddress(IP) { document.getElementById("lanip").innerHTML = IP; }  </script>
<applet code="MyAddress.class" MAYSCRIPT width=0 height=0>You Need To Enable Java For This To Work</applet>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Увы, такое уже пробовала - выдается внешний ip :(

Comment: посмотри апдейт ответа ;)